# Написать функцию покупка товара и добавление его в корзину магазина

Tags: python

Написать функцию покупка товара и добавление его в корзину магазина.
Есть магазин:

```
shop = {
    "мучное": {
        "хлеб": 200
    },
    "молочное":{
        "молоко":50
    },
    "мясное": {
        "говядина":500
    }
}
# Создаем словарь 
shopping_cart = {}
```

Теперь создаем функцию которая исходя из запроса пользователя брала бы товал из shop, перезаписывала в новый словарь нашу корзину shopping_cart удаляла купленный товар из shop и выводила вы приобрели товар и какие товары лежат в корзине, и опять выводила предложение о покупке и список оставшихся товаров в shop.
При условии, что в корзину можно добавить только те товары которые есть в магазине.
Но как это сделать я не знаю подскажите.

Comment: Ну так создавайте. Проблема-то в чем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот готовый вариант, который будет работать при заданном словаре. Программа не будет работать, если там будет куча вложенных словарей потому, что я не вижу в этом потребностей. Если надо это сделать, то я могу попробовать.

```
shop = {
"мучное": {
    "хлеб": 200
},
"молочное":{
    "молоко":50
},
"мясное": {
    "говядина":500
}
shopping_cart = {}

def buy(name):
    global shop, shopping_cart
    for keys in shop.keys():
        for keys2 in shop[keys].keys():
            if keys2 == name:
                shopping_cart[name] = shop[keys][name]
                del shop[keys][name]
                if len(shop[keys]) == 0: del shop[keys]
                print('Вы купили товары:', shopping_cart)
                return
    print('Такого товара нет')
while len(shop) > 0:
    name = input('Товар, который вы хотите купить:').lower()
    buy(name)

print('Все.Товары закончились')
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот полностью рабочий и универсальный вариант. Код довольно простой, разобраться можно просто прочитав пошагово, имена переменных будут объяснять происходящее. Категории и товары так же можно добавлять в любых количествах.

```
class Store:
    def __init__(self):
        self.shop = {
            'мучное': {
                'хлеб': 200,

            },
            'молочное': {
                'молоко': 50
            },
            "мясное": {
                "говядина": 500
                }
        }

        self.shopping_cart = {}

    def search_category(self, product):
        for item in self.shop:
            for category in self.shop[item]:
                if product == category:
                    product_price = self.shop[item].get(product)
                    return item, product_price
        else:
            return None, None

    def buying(self, product):
        category, product_price = self.search_category(product)
        if category:
            self.shop[category].pop(product)
            try:
                self.shopping_cart[category] = self.shopping_cart[category], {product: product_price}
            except:
                self.shopping_cart[category] = {product: product_price}
            return True
        else:
            return


store = Store()
while True:
    purchase = store.buying(str(input('Введите желаемый товар: ').lower()))
    if purchase:
        products = ', '.join([item for item in store.shop for item in store.shop[item]])
        purchases = ', '.join([item for item in store.shopping_cart for item in store.shopping_cart[item]])

        print(f'Покупка совершена. \nДоступные товары: {products}. \nСодержимое корзины: {purchases}')
    else:
        print('Данного товара нет в магазине.')
```

Comment: Мы пока не дошли до классов.